# Where can I get the "kernel-default-debuginfo" package for SLES 11?

Tags: linux, package-management, suse, sles

I'm using SLES 11 SP2 x86_64 and I want to install `kernel-default-debuginfo` package. But, I couldn't find it anywhere on the Novel website. Where can I find the mentioned package?

Answer (score 3):

This article would seem to explain what you're looking for, titled: [HOWTO: install kernel debuginfo packages on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11](http://blog.melski.net/2010/11/30/howto-install-kernel-debuginfo-packages-on-suse-linux-enterprise-server-11/).

*excerpts from that article*

#### 1. Get a list of repos

```
lin4-ea6:~ # zypper repos
# | Alias                                                    | Name                                                   | Enabled | Refresh
--+----------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------
1 | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Server-11 11-0                     | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Server-11 11-0                   | Yes     | No     
2 | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Software-Development-Kit-11_11-0   | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Software-Development-Kit-11 11-0 | Yes     | No     
3 | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Software-Development-Kit-11_11-0_1 | SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Software-Development-Kit-11 11-0 | Yes     | No     
4 | nu_novell_com:SLE11-Debuginfo-Pool                       | SLE11-Debuginfo-Pool                                   | No      | Yes    
5 | nu_novell_com:SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates                    | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates                                | No      | Yes    
6 | nu_novell_com:SLES11-Extras                              | SLES11-Extras                                          | No      | Yes    
7 | nu_novell_com:SLES11-Pool                                | SLES11-Pool                                            | No      | Yes    
8 | nu_novell_com:SLES11-Updates                             | SLES11-Updates                                         | Yes     | Yes
```

#### 2. Enable repos

You want the two Debuginfo repos. To enable them, use `zypper modifyrepo` with the alias of the repo:

```
lin4-ea6:~ # zypper modifyrepo --enable nu_novell_com:SLE11-Debuginfo-Pool
Repository 'nu_novell_com:SLE11-Debuginfo-Pool' has been sucessfully enabled.
lin4-ea6:~ # zypper modifyrepo --enable nu_novell_com:SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
Repository 'nu_novell_com:SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates' has been sucessfully enabled
```

#### 3. Search for your kernel's debuginfo

```
lin4-ea6:~ # zypper search -s kernel-*-debuginfo*

Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name                     | Type    | Version          | Arch | Repository             
--+--------------------------+---------+------------------+------+------------------------
  | kernel-default-debuginfo | package | 2.6.27.54-0.2.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-default-debuginfo | package | 2.6.27.48-0.12.1 | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-default-debuginfo | package | 2.6.27.48-0.6.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-default-debuginfo | package | 2.6.27.48-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-default-debuginfo | package | 2.6.27.45-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-default-debuginfo | package | 2.6.27.42-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-default-debuginfo | package | 2.6.27.39-0.3.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-default-debuginfo | package | 2.6.27.37-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-default-debuginfo | package | 2.6.27.29-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-default-debuginfo | package | 2.6.27.25-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-default-debuginfo | package | 2.6.27.23-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-default-debuginfo | package | 2.6.27.21-0.1.2  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-default-debuginfo | package | 2.6.27.19-5.1    | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Pool   
  | kernel-pae-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.54-0.2.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-pae-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.48-0.12.1 | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-pae-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.48-0.6.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-pae-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.48-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-pae-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.45-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-pae-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.42-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-pae-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.39-0.3.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-pae-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.37-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-pae-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.29-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-pae-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.25-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-pae-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.23-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-pae-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.21-0.1.2  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-pae-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.19-5.1    | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Pool   
  | kernel-source-debuginfo  | package | 2.6.27.54-0.2.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-source-debuginfo  | package | 2.6.27.48-0.12.1 | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-source-debuginfo  | package | 2.6.27.48-0.6.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-source-debuginfo  | package | 2.6.27.48-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-source-debuginfo  | package | 2.6.27.45-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-source-debuginfo  | package | 2.6.27.42-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-source-debuginfo  | package | 2.6.27.39-0.3.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-source-debuginfo  | package | 2.6.27.37-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-source-debuginfo  | package | 2.6.27.29-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-source-debuginfo  | package | 2.6.27.25-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-source-debuginfo  | package | 2.6.27.23-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-source-debuginfo  | package | 2.6.27.21-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-source-debuginfo  | package | 2.6.27.19-5.1    | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Pool   
  | kernel-vmi-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.54-0.2.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-vmi-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.48-0.12.1 | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-vmi-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.48-0.6.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-vmi-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.48-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-vmi-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.45-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-vmi-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.42-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-vmi-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.39-0.3.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-vmi-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.37-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-vmi-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.29-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-vmi-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.25-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-vmi-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.23-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-vmi-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.21-0.1.2  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-vmi-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.19-5.1    | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Pool   
  | kernel-xen-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.54-0.2.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-xen-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.48-0.12.1 | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-xen-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.48-0.6.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-xen-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.48-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-xen-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.45-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-xen-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.42-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-xen-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.39-0.3.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-xen-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.37-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-xen-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.29-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-xen-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.25-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-xen-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.23-0.1.1  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-xen-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.21-0.1.2  | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Updates
  | kernel-xen-debuginfo     | package | 2.6.27.19-5.1    | i586 | SLE11-Debuginfo-Pool
```

#### 4. Install package

```
lin4-ea6:~ # zypper install kernel-pae-debuginfo=2.6.27.45-0.1.1
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

The following NEW package is going to be installed:
  kernel-pae-debuginfo 


The following package is not supported by its vendor:
  kernel-pae-debuginfo 


Overall download size: 153.1 M. After the operation, additional 673.8 M will be used.
Continue? [YES/no]: 
...
...
Retrieving package kernel-pae-debuginfo-2.6.27.45-0.1.1.i586 (1/1), 153.1 M (673.8 M unpacked)
Retrieving: kernel-pae-debuginfo-2.6.27.45-0.1.1.i586.rpm [done (244.7 K/s)]
Installing: kernel-pae-debuginfo-2.6.27.45-0.1.1 [done]
```

Comment: Also [this](http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=3074997).

Comment: Thanks. But, I actually wanted to know where this package is available. I need the link/webpage/path of the repository.

Comment: @MandarShinde - you could use zypper to download only: http://blog.christophersmart.com/2010/02/01/zypper-download-only-option/